# Hub signalr not found in Maui library class

Tags: c#, signalr, maui

I've just created new `MAUI library project` and added package from nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` nevertheless on `class` level `Hub` is not found and i am getting error:

```
The type or namespace Hub could not be found.
```

Strange as in other project like `Blazor App` there is no issue at all doing the same. Any thoughts?

**Full code:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ServicesMauiLib
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR `Hub` is something that you use on a server application so it doesn't make sense to be included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` package.

The `Hub` class was included in the core `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` which is now [deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42601).

> In 3.1 we moved to the "shared framework" concept. This made it so we
> don't need to release a lot of the packages that were released before
> and they are now included by default when you build an ASP.NET Core
> application. This is what happened to the SignalR server packages,
> they are now included in the shared framework and we no longer produce
> a standalone package.
>
> Another common question is "how do I write a library for server
> applications that uses SignalR?". This can be done by adding a
> reference to the shared framework in your library. See
> https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
> for details.

So basically you need to add the following to the `.csproj` file of your library.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: as far as i know Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client is the most recent package we should use (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client)  and it includes both server and client which is proved as in blazor/maui app it works. It just doesnt work on maui library.

Comment: No, what you said is incorrect. As you can read in the documentation "projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` MSBuild SDK **implicitly reference** the shared framework. Projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK **must reference** ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework.". So in projects like `Blazor Server`, `MVC`, `Razor Pages`, `Web API` you can use the `Hub` class which is included in the shared framework. In projects like `Blazor WebAssemply`, `MAUI` or class libraries you have to do what already described in my answer.

Comment: but basically if i do the way u described by adding it directly in .csproj it's still not the way as depreceated right?

Comment: In the past you could use this: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="x.x.x" />`. This package is now [deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR) and SignalR is included in the shared framework so now you have to do: `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` package [is not deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) and you can still use it when you only need the SignalR client.